# Scipy Kolmogorov Smirnov test

Tags: kolmogorov-smirnov-test, scipy

I wanted to know what is significance level (alpha) in scipy's Kolmogorov test.
[Here is a link to documentation page.](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.kstest.html)
I couldn't find anything in its documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because the test does not return a significance level. You choose the significance level. Commonly this is 5%, but in many domains it is not.

Comment: I got a little bit confused... is significance level sth that we choose during test or find the best one to describe our sample by experience...

Comment: You choose the significance level before doing the test. If you have a further question, please make a new post and give as much detail about your situation as possible.